# Appcompat res values-v21 themes_base errors on eclipse are not going away

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-appcompat

**I had checked for the questions and have not found a suitable answer for my problem**

```
+ [2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:220: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlNormal'.
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:225: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlNormal'.
[2014-11-21 16:12:02 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:14:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
[2014-11-21 16:14:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:14:50 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:74: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextBackground'.
..................................
........................................
[2014-11-21 16:15:48 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:15:48 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:225: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-11-21 16:15:48 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-21 16:15:48 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\MISC\canvas\eclipse workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlNormal'.
```

**Project properties are the same for my app and the appcompat v7 too. The target is set to 21 for both appcompat and my app** .
The error was at styles_base and later **after following** some answers it jumped to themes base.
I had even reinstalled java and eclipse.

**Please what should I do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your project with the API 21 SDK to Let your project know about resource for API 21.
Don't forget to clean and re-build.

Comment: This worked for me. I changed targets of appcombat and all the projects importing it to api 21. Then cleaned and re-built the projects. I even had to restart eclipse once. (Because I had updated the appcombat lib).

Answer (score 0):

First check if Eclipse includes appcompat_v21 on your Library path.

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android

[image]

Check if the project appcompat_v21 is checked.

If it doesn't solve your problem. Carefully check the your

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

And change android:theme into:

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Then, clean your project and it should be fine.

Comment: These are all correct. But nothing happens, the errors remain over there. I am confused, I really don't know what I could do...

Comment: Even when you change your AndroidManifest theme is still giving you error messages?

Comment: It is already at android:theme="@style/AppTheme", I didn't have to change it Sir...

Comment: Not the best approach, but try opening your themes_base.xml and removing the wrong references

Comment: The entire thing shows error, I cannot delete them, the whole xml file will go blank if i do that..

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in appcompat_v7 support lib
in values-21\themes_base.xml that

error retrieving parrent Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat

than i completely delete project from workspase and update Android Support Library to 21.0.2
and re-import library from extras\android.....appcompat

problem solved
i hope this helps you